# Query on large i18n table slow in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.3

The query below, using CakePHP's i18n table, takes around 1000ms to run.  My i18n table is large - it has around 600,000 rows.  I have the default indexes on this table, as per the Cake schema.

How can I speed queries like this up?  I am caching them where possible but when the cache needs to be cleared these queries are run, and they slow down the performance quite noticeably.

```
SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`slug`, `Category`.`name`, `Category`.`description`, `Category`.`head_title`, `Category`.`display_title`, `Category`.`category_count`, `Category`.`product_count`, `Category`.`parent_id`, `Category`.`lft`, `Category`.`rght`, `Category`.`sort_order`, `Category`.`created`, `Category`.`modified`, `Category`.`image_processed`, ((rght - lft) = 1) AS `Category__is_child`, (`I18n__name`.`content`) AS `Category__i18n_name`, (`I18n__description`.`content`) AS `Category__i18n_description`, (`I18n__slug`.`content`) AS `Category__i18n_slug`, (`I18n__head_title`.`content`) AS `Category__i18n_head_title`, (`I18n__meta_description`.`content`) AS `Category__i18n_meta_description`, (`I18n__heading_title`.`content`) AS `Category__i18n_heading_title` FROM `fracmerl_dev`.`categories` AS `Category`
    INNER JOIN `fracmerl_dev`.`i18n` AS `I18n__name` 
        ON (`Category`.`id` = `I18n__name`.`foreign_key`
        AND `I18n__name`.`model` = 'Category' 
        AND `I18n__name`.`field` = 'name'
        AND `I18n__name`.`locale` = 'eng')
    INNER JOIN `fracmerl_dev`.`i18n` AS `I18n__description`
        ON (`Category`.`id` = `I18n__description`.`foreign_key`
        AND `I18n__description`.`model` = 'Category'
        AND `I18n__description`.`field` = 'description' 
        AND `I18n__description`.`locale` = 'eng')
    INNER JOIN `fracmerl_dev`.`i18n` AS `I18n__slug`
        ON (`Category`.`id` = `I18n__slug`.`foreign_key`
        AND `I18n__slug`.`model` = 'Category'
        AND `I18n__slug`.`field` = 'slug'
        AND `I18n__slug`.`locale` = 'eng')
    INNER JOIN `fracmerl_dev`.`i18n` AS `I18n__head_title`
        ON (`Category`.`id` = `I18n__head_title`.`foreign_key`
        AND `I18n__head_title`.`model` = 'Category'
        AND `I18n__head_title`.`field` = 'head_title'
        AND `I18n__head_title`.`locale` = 'eng')
    INNER JOIN `fracmerl_dev`.`i18n` AS `I18n__meta_description`
        ON (`Category`.`id` = `I18n__meta_description`.`foreign_key`
        AND `I18n__meta_description`.`model` = 'Category'
        AND `I18n__meta_description`.`field` = 'meta_description'
        AND `I18n__meta_description`.`locale` = 'eng')
    INNER JOIN `fracmerl_dev`.`i18n` AS `I18n__heading_title`
        ON (`Category`.`id` = `I18n__heading_title`.`foreign_key`
        AND `I18n__heading_title`.`model` = 'Category'
        AND `I18n__heading_title`.`field` = 'heading_title'
        AND `I18n__heading_title`.`locale` = 'eng')
WHERE `I18n__slug`.`content` = 'category-slug'
ORDER BY `Category`.`sort_order` ASC, `Category`.`name` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Edit - the indexes, the result of `SHOW INDEX FROM i18n`

```
i18n    0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   598455  NULL    NULL        BTREE
i18n    1   locale  1   locale  A   5   NULL    NULL        BTREE
i18n    1   model   1   model   A   3   NULL    NULL        BTREE
i18n    1   row_id  1   foreign_key A   18701   NULL  NULL  BTREE
i18n    1   field   1   field   A   9   NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

Comment: Please supply your indexes

Comment: Thanks Dave, have added these to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If your i18n table is large try to split it up and use [Multiple Translation Tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html#multiple-translation-tables).

Comment: Thanks - 90% of the rows in my translation table are for the same model though.  I may try it anyway if I can't speed things up any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to shift conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` which join table. Generally, there should no difference, but if query optimizer work wrong or ineffective, then earlier conditions reduce amount of rows  and so improve performance.

some links:

- [Condition within JOIN or WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018952/condition-within-join-or-where)
- [Inner join vs Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where)

forget to said, of cause, I mean that you can

```
`I18n__slug`.`content` = 'category-slug'
```

move to ON statement.

Something like:

```
INNER JOIN `fracmerl_dev`.`i18n` AS `I18n__slug`
    ON (
    `I18n__slug`.`content` = 'category-slug'
    AND `Category`.`id` = `I18n__slug`.`foreign_key`
    AND `I18n__slugs`.`model` = 'Category'
    AND `I18n__slug`.`field` = 'slug'
    AND `I18n__slug`.`locale` = 'eng')
```