# What is difference between writing filter condition in join and after where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is difference between below queries

```
Select  E.EmployeeCode,E.Name,D.DepartmentCode,D.DepartmentName
From Employee E
inner join Department D on D.DepartmentID=E.DepartmentID
Where e.EmployeeType='Developer'
```

Vs

```
Select  E.EmployeeCode,E.Name,D.DepartmentCode,D.DepartmentName
From Employee E
inner join Department D on D.DepartmentID=E.DepartmentID And e.EmployeeType='Developer'
```

I am asking in terms of performance.
How above query performe with huge data in tables

Comment: No difference at all, when you're doing an inner join. (When it comes to outer join, they've got different results...)

Comment: It's popular problem and there was several threads like this. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018952/condition-within-join-or-where

Comment: For outer joins there may be significant difference. For the cases where condition placing does not affect result this is only a style and personal preferences question. Not related to the join itself conditions I'd recommend to place in `where`. Like your `employeetype='developer'`. It is not related to joining and is a bit confusing. Like you forgot something or actually wanted a `left join`.

Answer (score 3):

For an `INNER JOIN` there is no difference. The execution plan for each query is identical.

[image: SQL Execution Plan]

The first plan is for the query:

```
Select  E.EmployeeCode,E.Name,D.DepartmentCode,D.DepartmentName
From Employee E
inner join Department D on D.DepartmentID=E.DepartmentID
Where e.EmployeeType='Developer'
```

And the second plan is for the query:

```
Select  E.EmployeeCode,E.Name,D.DepartmentCode,D.DepartmentName
From Employee E
inner join Department D on D.DepartmentID=E.DepartmentID And e.EmployeeType='Developer'
```

Therefore the performance of either query will be the same.

With "huge" data you may need indexes on the columns you are using in the `WHERE` and `JOIN` condition, depending on the uniqueness of values in those columns. In the query plans in the screenshot you can see SQL Sever is performing a Table Scan, so you might want to change that.