# Selecting from more than two tables using join selects duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have 3 table on my mysql db (user, follower, post), I wrote an sql, that get all posts from the people a user followed.

**sql**

```
SELECT post.* FROM post JOIN
       follower ON post.owner_user_id = follower.user_id AND
       follower.follower_id = "3"
```

**result**

```
id | owner_user_id | content
2  | 1             | why are all my senior developers jerks?
3  | 1             | PHP7 in your face node.js
```

**user table**

```
id | username | password
 1 | user1    | 12345678
 2 | user2    | 12345678
 3 | user3    | 12345678
```

**follower table**

```
user_id | follower_id
3       | 1
3       | 2
1       | 3
```

**post table**

```
id | owner_user_id | content
1  | 2             | reading a 1k+ page on mysql, do i need to?
2  | 1             | why are all my senior developers jerks?
3  | 1             | PHP7!, in your face node.js
3  | 3             | I posted
```

so now am trying to select post of people the user is following and the posts of the user

I tried this sql

**sql**

```
SELECT post.* FROM post JOIN
       follower ON post.owner_user_id = follower.user_id AND
       follower.follower_id = "3" JOIN
       user ON post.owner_user_id = user.id= "3"
```

**result**

```
null
```

Please is what am trying to achieve with the sql possible,
if(possible) {"what_am_i_doing_wrong"}();

***edits***

```
user_id 3 has a post, still running the above sql returns null, was hoping if the user had no post, only post of the people the user is following is returned
```

Comment: why arent you using `WHERE` conditions?

Comment: You didn't get anything because there is no value 3 for  owner_user_id

Comment: @shanu k k but aren't i suppose to get the post of people the user is following then?

Comment: @JustJacob - add value 3 to post table and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select post.* from 
(select user_id from follower where follower_id = 3 union select 3) blah 
join post on blah.user_id = post.owner_user_id;
```

Comment: Wow, this work like magic literally like magic, i don't have a "blah" in my tables, how the hell did this not return errors, i have got a lot to learn in mysql.

OOh and thank you!

Comment: It's an alias. You can change it for a more meaningful identifier.

Comment: can i follow you on twitter. or you website.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Distinct post.* FROM post JOIN
   follower ON post.owner_user_id = follower.user_id JOIN
   user ON follower.user_id = user.id WHERE user.id = 3
```

You shuldn't use conditions in JOIN statement, use WHERE instead.

Comment: I tried this but it returned 2 duplicates of user 3's post. and nothing more

Comment: now it just returns the single user 3's post, but am trying to return user 3's post and post of people user 3 follows. siloko's answer did just that, thanks for your answer though i appreciate.

Comment: "You shuldn't use conditions in JOIN statement, use WHERE instead" -- it makes sense to me to put the search conditions in the same place. What's the advantage of putting some in the `JOIN` and others in the `WHERE`?

Comment: @onedaywhen Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1019006/6371926
"...may already be excluded during the JOIN process.". I hope this helps u :D

Comment: @AlbertoLópezPérez: I don't understand your point. If we agree that it makes no difference to optimizer, which can rearrange things as it sees fit, and ultimately "it depends, of course", why then do you say "You shuldn't" ?

Comment: because the conditions that are inside the joins, can be excluded because is "in the middle of de code" and the where statement is at the end of the query and this condition (in the where) is overall query.