# Performance : Between in FROM or in WHERE?

Tags: sql

I ask myself what is the more performance method when you join table and use JOIN in clause FROM and when you need to use BETWEEN :

- Use Between in the FROM

or

- Use between in the WHERE

Exemple :

```
SELECT *
FROM Tab1 a inner join Tab2 b 
on (a.pk=b.fk_1 AND a.date between b.date1 and b.date2)
```

Versus

```
SELECT *
FROM Tab1 a inner join Tab2 b 
on a.pk=b.fk_1  
WHERE a.date between b.date1 and b.date2
```

Which one is the best?

Thank

P.S : sorry for my bad english

Comment: Take a llok here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018952/condition-within-join-or-where

Comment: Try them both and see which one has the best performance. If the difference is negligible, then it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: They should both produce the same execution plan and optimization.  I prefer the first version, because the `between` condition combines columns from both tables, so it is logically part of the `join` condition.

Comment: Thank Kostis, this answer my question

Comment: performs wise they should be the same, but preference, I prefer the second in that `ON` should be for relationships and `WHERE` used for other filtering