# How to sanitize join params inside a controller in Rails 4?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, controller, sanitize

Is this, the best way to sanitize 'join' params inside a Controller in Rails 4?

assume:

```
user_name = params[:user_name]
```

.

```
# That's the only way that I can figure this out:
@result = Agenda.joins("LEFT JOIN meetings AS me ON meetings.agenda_id = agendas.id WHERE me.name = #{Agenda.sanitize(user_name})"
```

I have tried this but don't works because 'joins' expect tables after each ',':

```
@result = Agenda.joins("LEFT JOIN meetings AS me ON meetings.agenda_id = agendas.id WHERE me.name = ?", user_name)
```

Note:
This is just a bit of the code to explain the problem, in the full code I really have to use the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Take away the WHERE clause, it could be added then, like `Agenda.joins('LEFT JOIN meetings ON meetings.agenda_id = agendas.id').where('meetings.name = ?', user_name)`.

Comment: Why not use `Agenda.joins(:meetings).where(meetings: { name: user_name })`?

Comment: As this made me curious: i came across this question where the final consensus seems to be that DBs will most likely have the same performance on queries with the WHERE condition inside as well as outside of the JOIN. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018952/condition-within-join-or-where

Comment: Thanks by the comments about the query, I will really think about rewrite them using 'where'.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution using

> Model.send(:sanitize_sql_array, < query >)

eg:

```
user_name = params[:user_name]

join = "LEFT JOIN meetings AS me 
        ON meetings.agenda_id = agendas.id 
        WHERE me.name = ?", user_name)"

join = Agenda.send(:sanitize_sql_array,join)

@result = Agenda.joins(join)
```

In this format, you can use as many parameters as you need with any type of query.

Comment: Mind you that this is a protected method.