# Strange select behaviour: Join works, where clause does not - WHY and since WHEN?

Tags: sql, join, select, where-clause, abap

I experienced a strange behaviour, and I already was thinking of looking for a proper shrink. Can anyone explain this one here ?

This select returns, what I want:

```
SELECT struc~node,struc~tree_level,struc~parent,
       strut~ltext,
       mar~matnr, mar~mtart, mar~matkl,
       mtx~maktx

    FROM            wrf_matgrp_struc AS struc

    LEFT OUTER JOIN wrf_matgrp_strct AS strut
            ON strut~hier_id = struc~hier_id
           AND strut~node    = struc~node

    LEFT OUTER JOIN wrf_matgrp_sku AS sku
            ON sku~hier_id = struc~hier_id
           AND sku~node    = struc~node

    LEFT OUTER JOIN mara AS mar
            ON mar~matnr = sku~matnr

    LEFT OUTER JOIN maw1 AS maw
            ON maw~matnr = mar~matnr

    LEFT OUTER JOIN makt AS mtx
           ON mtx~matnr = mar~matnr
          AND mtx~spras = strut~spras

    INTO TABLE @lt_result_tab
          WHERE struc~hier_id    = @gs_act_hier-hier_id
            AND struc~node      IN @grt_node
            AND struc~date_from <= @sy-datum
            AND struc~date_to   >= @sy-datum
            AND strut~spras      = @sy-langu
            AND mar~matnr       IN @grt_matnr
            AND mar~matkl       IN @grt_matkl
            AND maw~wekgr       IN @grt_wekgr
```

I remove the join **AND mtx~spras = strut~spras** and place it into a where condition like this, and it does not work as expected ( resultset is incomplete ).

```
SELECT struc~node,struc~tree_level,struc~parent,
       strut~ltext,
       mar~matnr, mar~mtart, mar~matkl,
       mtx~maktx

    FROM            wrf_matgrp_struc AS struc

    LEFT OUTER JOIN wrf_matgrp_strct AS strut
            ON strut~hier_id = struc~hier_id
           AND strut~node    = struc~node

    LEFT OUTER JOIN wrf_matgrp_sku AS sku
            ON sku~hier_id = struc~hier_id
           AND sku~node    = struc~node

    LEFT OUTER JOIN mara AS mar
            ON mar~matnr = sku~matnr

    LEFT OUTER JOIN maw1 AS maw
            ON maw~matnr = mar~matnr

    LEFT OUTER JOIN makt AS mtx
           ON mtx~matnr = mar~matnr

    INTO TABLE @lt_result_tab
          WHERE struc~hier_id    = @gs_act_hier-hier_id
            AND struc~node      IN @grt_node
            AND struc~date_from <= @sy-datum
            AND struc~date_to   >= @sy-datum
            AND strut~spras      = @sy-langu
            AND mar~matnr       IN @grt_matnr
            AND mar~matkl       IN @grt_matkl
            AND maw~wekgr       IN @grt_wekgr
            AND mtx~spras        = @sy-langu.
```

Comment: By moving the comparison to the `where` clause, you've turned the `left join` into an `inner join`

Comment: Wait, is this REALLY true ? OUTER JOIN = if You find some entries, apply the where clause, else go home.

Comment: If you were using an old system, it would tell you "you cannot put fields from an LEFT JOIN in the WHERE clause"... I guess it's the same for your SQLs :(

Comment: As You already see, this is a new one. And I know the restriction on older systems, therefore I am pretty satisfied , that they extended the where conditions.

Comment: I am too, but I was trying to point the fact SAP considers different a condition within the WHERE clause than within the JOIN one, and maybe (maybe, I say) it's the cause of your weird behavior.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAP, but I've never come across a definition of an `outer join` as you posted. When you use an `outer join`, the outer joined table contains `null` values in all columns for non matching rows. Since `[something] = null` evaluates to `null` (not `true`), the comparison in the `where` filters out all non matching rows: inner join behaviour. I'm confident this is true in SAP as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019432/1474519

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)